# Ionic post to facebook wall

Tags: facebook, cordova, android-intent, ionic-framework

I am developing an app with Ionic and I want the user to be able to send a preset message on his wall on facebook. I don't need any authentication with facebook. I know it was possible with native android app, with Intent. There is a facebook pluging for cordova but I want something lighter, I don't want to have to connect the user from facebook. So I was wondering if I could use a kind of Intent to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With authorization, you can use the [`/me/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish) endpoint. But keep in mind that prefilling the message is not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Without authorization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#triggering

Look at the example code, it should be fairly easy to create your own Cordova plugin with Java if there is no plugin yet. Or just try one of the existing ones, for example: https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-facebook#share